# UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in IOS8.0, then how to init it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

**`UISearchDisplayController`** is deprecated in **`IOS8.0`**, and recommended to use **`UISearchController`** instead.

Then How to use the new **`API**` to implement the flowing :

(from **`Beginning IOS7 Development Exploring the IOS SDK`**)

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
searchContoller = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]
                     initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                     contentsController:self];
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
```

You know, the **API** in **`UISearchController`** is different, then how to do ?

Answer (score 2):

From [APPLE DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/searchBar):

```
searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Check this [SAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController) on UISearchController.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project that replaces the UISearchDisplayController with UISearchController based off the Vea Software tutorial video found on youtube.

https://github.com/2015HuntMJ/UISearchController

NOTE: the above project uses swift